# How to display preselected checkboxes in a Struts2 Iterator

Tags: javascript, checkbox, struts2, struts-tags

I'm displaying a list as checkboxes. In this some checkboxes should be prechecked based on the database values.
If I use checkboxlist I can achive this, but I'm able to display only one property(`listValue`) after checkbox. I need to display more than one property after checkbox.

```
<s:checkboxlist list="myList" name="checkboxes" listKey="id" listValue="name" value="selectedList"/>
```

here `myList` has the available checkboxes and `selectedList` contain the keys that should be precheked

So how to achieve the same functionality with a checkbox in an iterator...?
The code that I have tried to display available checkboxes are...

```
<s:iterator value="myList" var="record">
  <s:checkbox name="id" value="%{#record.id}"/>
  <s:property value="#record.name"/>
  <s:property value="#record.description"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<s:checkboxlist>` tag you can simply concatenate properties in `listValue` attribute.

```
<s:checkboxlist list="myList" 
                name="checkboxes" 
                listKey="id" 
                listValue="name +' '+ description" 
                value="selectedList" />
```

If you prefer to iterate over list by yourself use list's `contains` method to set some checkboxes as checked.

Note that `value` attribute of `<s:checkbox>` tag is for setting if checkbox will be checked or not. To set value which will be sent to server you need to use `fieldValue` attribute.

```
<s:iterator value="records" var="record">
    <label>
        <s:checkbox name="id" 
                    fieldValue="%{#record.id}" 
                    value="selectedList.contains(#record.id)" />

        <s:property value="#record.name" />
        <s:property value="#record.description" />
    </label>
</s:iterator>
```

Don't forget about labels, by using them you can check checkboxes by clicking on label text.